# Nginx reverse proxy to apache server, redirection gives 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, server, reverse-proxy

I have this setup with angular and spring boot project having nginx reverse proxy to apache for serving angular application and embedded server for spring boot reverse proxied through nginx. Now I am loading angular alright but when it comes to making request to spring boot server it gives a 404. I tried to curl the `localhost:8085/api/hello`, it works, or exposing localhost to public through tunnelling,
it works fine. I am missing something in configuration only.

Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       154.62.107.99:80 default;
    server_name  _;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/154.62.107.99.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://154.62.107.99:8080;
   }
   location /api/ {

        # Simple requests
      if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
         add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "*";
      }


     proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8085/;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   }
}

server {
    listen      154.62.107.99:443 ssl http2;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.key;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/154.62.107.99_https.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_https.log debug;

   # return 301 http://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
      #  root /var/www/document_errors/;

       # Handle preflight requests (OPTIONS)
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "*";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            return 200;
        }

        # Handle other requests
        # Add any additional configuration for handling other requests

        # Redirect other requests
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias /var/www/document_errors/;
    }
}
```

here I am trying to redirect all request with `/` to apache server running on `8080`. I need to redirect all request with `/api/` to my spring boot server.

I doubt it this reverse proxy things is even working. Here are few observations:

1. Stopping nginx server causes site not to load, hence request is being served from there.
2. Stopping apache server give internal server error
3. for location `/` when I comment out the line `proxy_pass http://154.62.107.99:8080` , it still loads the frontend, which is surprising because I though I was redirecting request to apache from nginx. I don't understand how this is happening.

Update::

This is my apache2 configuration

```
Listen 154.62.107.99:8443
Listen 154.62.107.99:8080
<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8080>
    ServerName 154.62.107.99
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Alias /error/ /var/www/document_errors/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8443>
    ServerName 154.62.107.99
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Alias /error/ /var/www/document_errors/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile         /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile      /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Now content of dist folder are not at /var/www/html, it just contains a success file. Now when I stop the apache2 , I get internal server error and page doesn't loads, but angular project for sure is not being served from here in apache2.

It has another configuration file in `/domains` directory which correctly configures the Document root.

```
<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8080>

    ServerName nirbhaysingh.dev
    ServerAlias www.nirbhaysingh.dev
    ServerAdmin info@nirbhaysingh.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.error.log

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/apache2.forcessl.conf*

    <Directory /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm-nirbhaysingh.dev.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/apache2.conf_*
    IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

My guess is that, redirection is failing, so content of angular application is either served directly from nginx as defined in its domains configuration. I am working on it and updating here as it goes

Comment: You state that `localhost:8085/api/hello` works, but your Nginx configuration is sending `localhost:8085/hello` - try `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8085;` (i.e. without the trailing `/`)